# Harry Potter fan-fiction with young Severus Snape potion accident

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a young Severus Snape fanfic I read.

I remember that Snape was in potion class and someone added something to the potion; he tried to put up a shield to contain the explosion but the shield didn't close completely and he was hurt, and the healers had a hard time stopping the bleeding

That's all I remember.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this yesterday?

Comment: Yes, Just join and it gave me a new account.

Comment: Okay, well, just so you know, please don't post the exact same question twice. It's considered poor form. Since you asked this one with a registered account, I'll do you a solid and vote to close the previous one as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know; I tried to delete it after opening this account but I couldn't figure it out.